# Replace single whitespaces with double

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have a bunch of XML files containing texts (transcriptions of a diary). At the end of sentences, the requirement is that there be two whitespaces after the period. At the moment, this is partially done, but not in all cases: sometimes there is only a single whitespace after the period before the first character of the next sentence.

I'm using Gitbash for Windows, and think that sed is the command to use, but I don't know the correct regular expression. I think I need to find:

> period whitespace [some other character]

and replace with

> period whitespace whitespace [the same next character]

For example, right now we have this:

`<p>The spacing after this sentence (two whitespaces) is what is required.  By contrast, this sentence has only a single space after the period. This is the next sentence, the last in a paragraph, which correctly has no whitespace at all after the period.</p>`

What I need is this, where each period is followed by two whitespaces, apart from the last in the paragraph.

`<p>The double whitespace after this sentence is what is required.  This sentence now also has a double space after the period.  This is the next sentence, the last in a paragraph, which correctly has no whitespace at all after the period.</p>`

Comment: Please post sample Input files in code tags in your post.

Comment: Can you please post a simple "before" and "after" examples? I don't get it from the examples you've posted.

Comment: What about question marks? Do you also need a double space?

Comment: An HTML parser will treat such unnecessary double spaces as a single space anyway; you'll need something like ' &nbsp;' instead. If the only reason you need to do this is that someone mistakenly believes this is the correct way to punctuate, you have my condolences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `sed` you can do this:

```
sed -e "s/\. \</\.  /"
```

Here are the changes

```
$ sed -e "s/\. \b/\.  /g" test.txt > fixed.txt
$ diff test.txt fixed.txt
1c1
< <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vehicula placerat nisl, bibendum blandit tortor pharetra ut. Morbi nec tellus ultrices, porta felis et, dapibus diam. Phasellus vehicula ante ac urna elementum lacinia.</p>
---
> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Maecenas vehicula placerat nisl, bibendum blandit tortor pharetra ut.  Morbi nec tellus ultrices, porta felis et, dapibus diam.  Phasellus vehicula ante ac urna elementum lacinia.</p>
```

Comment: This will fail if you have `a.<space><space>t`. It will add another space.

Comment: No it doesn't `$ echo "a.  t" | sed -e "s/\. \b/\.  /"` returns `a.  t`

Comment: This doesn't work at all, for me. Is `\b` perhaps specific to the variant of `sed` that you're running?

Comment: `\b` is the word boundary. It should work with all `sed` versions. Try to replace `\b` with `\\b`.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that `\b` is a GNU extension. Perhaps you're looking for `\<`?

Comment: @ghoti Interesting. I didn't know about that. It is sad that `sed` doesn't support `POSIX Extended Regular Expression Syntax`

Comment: @nowox, sed, and for that matter regular expressions, predate POSIX. You must forgive the developers their lack of precognition. :) That said, I've seen reference to "[POSIX word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#posix)" that look like character classes, but I don't see any reference to them in [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09). `man re_format` on my system reports "***This is an extension, compatible with but not specified by IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'')***."

Comment: @ghoti, I think that **BRE** and **ERE** which are very *very* old should be replaced with **PCRE**.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is a little bit limited (can you use `grep` or `perl`?) anyway you can use a regex like this (*GNU sed specific*):

```
sed -i -r 's/\. ([^ ])/.  \1/g'  <file>
```

**Legenda**

```
-i         # sed switch: replace inplace in the file passed as parameter
-r         # use extended regex 
/\. ([^ ]) # match a single dot followed by a space and by a not-space
/.  \1/    # replace with a dot follower by 2 spaces and by the previous non-space char
g          # apply multiple times per line
```

The regex could be refined if needed with more test cases.

As evidenced by @ghoti the answer was *GNU sed* specific. I think a more general approach (without extended regex and inplace) could be:

```
sed 's/\. \([^ ]\)/.  \1/g' <input.file> > <output.file>
```

Comment: Worth noting that this answer is specific to GNU sed, and is likely not portable to other variants. In particular, `-i` is an issue, and older BSD seds use `-E` instead of `-r`. (I believe this is still the case in macOS.) If you provide a platform-speciic answer to a general or non-platform-specific question, it's always best to qualify the limitations of your answer.

Comment: @ghoti thank you for your specification. I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all the white space occurrences after a dot and remember the next character. Then replace with ".  " and whatever the remembered character was. The remembering part is called a "tagged expression".

So, search for `\. +([^ ])` which means "dot, some spaces, [tagged expression]something that isn't a space[end tagged expression]"

Replace it with `.  \1`

Here's a sed example:

```
$ echo '>zzz. xxx.  yyy.<' | sed -r -e 's/\. +([^ ])/.  \1/g'
>zzz.  xxx.  yyy.<
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's-\. (?! )-\.  -g' test
```

Example:

```
$ cat test
This is. A simple.  Test to check. That it works!
$ perl -pe 's-\. (?! )-\.  -g' test
This is.  A simple.  Test to check.  That it works!
```

The regex `\. (?! )` matches a period, followed by a space, that's *not* followed by another space.