# replacing spaces with sed in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to edit a text file in Linux. I need to replace all sentences ending in a single space with double spaces. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's not fixing all of them, just some.

`sed 's/\.\s/.  /g' examplefile.txt`

Any nudge in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Can you see any pattern to the ones it's not fixing? Could they be going over a newline, or could it be fixing every-other-one, or something? I don't really have any guesses - but if you could copy a section of the file where it is fixing one, and is not fixing another, and edit into your question, that might help people spot what's happening.

Comment: [Insert space after period using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10524476/608639), [Replace single whitespaces with double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48987638/608639), [sed command to replace multiple spaces into single spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939323/608639), etc.

Comment: maybe some of the empty glyphs aren't spaces?